# deckInfo.keys is not a function or its return value is not iterable

Tags: reactjs, hashmap

I don't totally understand this error. I have a map with state. I iterate through the map and create multiple elements that use the map's keys and values. Each key and value get put into a text `input` field that has an onChange function. When I type in the `input` fields, I get an error message stating `deckInfo.keys is not a function or its return value is not iterable`. What is going on here?

`main jsx file`

```
...

const EditDeckRoute = ({deckID}) => {
    const url = "http://localhost:8080/api/deck/" + deckID

    const [deckInfo, setDeckInfo] = React.useState(new Map())

    React.useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(url).then((response) => {
            setDeckInfo(new Map(Object.entries(response.data)))
        })
    }, [])

    function newCard() {
        setDeckInfo(new Map(deckInfo.set("", "")))
    }

    const handleDeckInfoChange = e => {
        setDeckInfo(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value,

        }))
    }
    
    return (
        <>
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div className="header">
                <h1>Your Flashcards</h1>
                    <button onClick={newCard} >Add Card</button>
                </div>
                {
                    [...deckInfo.keys()].map((topic, num) => {
                        return <EditFlashcard key={num} topic={topic} description={deckInfo.get(topic)} change={handleDeckInfoChange} />
                    })
                }
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default EditDeckRoute;
```

`EditFlashcard.jsx`

```
import "./card.css"

const EditFlashcard = ({topic, description, change}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div className="review-flashcard-wrapper">
                <div className="review-flashcard" >
                    <div className="review-flashcard-topic">
                        <input type="text" name={topic} value={topic} onChange={change} ></input>
                    </div>
                    <div className="review-flashcard-desc">
                        <input type="text" name={description} value={description} onChange={change} ></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default EditFlashcard;
```

Comment: You use `setDeckInfo` to change it from `Map` to an object

Comment: @Konrad is that in the `handleDeckInfoChange` function? if so, how should i change it to be a map instead of an object?